# ORA-01465: invalid hex number in oracle while using BLOB

Tags: oracle, blob

i am designing a database in oracle 11g. I have designed a table with fields,

```
CUST_ID, NUMBER(5) //this is a foreign key
Review, BLOB //to store big strings 
Date, SYSDATE
```

now when i'm trying to insert data in the table like-

```
insert into "ReviewTable" values ( 3, 'hello, this is the first review',SYSDATE)
```

it gives [Err] ORA-01465: invalid hex number.
If someone can help me with the error?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

you cast your string into BLOB, you can do this via package `utl_raw.cast_to_raw` or convert varchar to clob via `to_clob('mystring')` and then use procedure `DBMS_LOB.convertToBlob` in your code

but if you are going to use the fields for string why don`t save them as a CLOB?

Here are 2 examples below with BLOB and CLOB fields

**BLOB**

```
create table ReviewTable( CUST_ID NUMBER(5)
,Review  BLOB  
,Dt Date);

insert into ReviewTable values ( 3, utl_raw.cast_to_raw('hello, this is the first review'),SYSDATE);
```

**CLOB**

```
create table ReviewTable2( CUST_ID NUMBER(5)
,Review  CLOB  
,Dt Date);

insert into ReviewTable2 values ( 3, 'hello, this is the first review',SYSDATE);
```