# How to resolve "invalid hex number" in by specifically passing id?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I have a "club" checkbox in events form which gets its list of values from "club" table

```
select club_id, club_name
from club;
```

When a user selects one or more checkboxes and submits a from, a page process takes the id's of those selected clubs and inserts them and the event_id inside club_event table. But I am getting an error stating "invalid hex number".

[image]

This is the script that I have used in my page process.

```
DECLARE
    l_ids apex_t_varchar2;
BEGIN
    l_ids := apex_string.split(:P72_CLUBS, ':');
    FOR i in 1 .. l_ids.COUNT LOOP
        INSERT INTO club_event
            VALUES(L_ids(i), :P72_EVENT_ID);
        END LOOP;
END;
```

The error must be occuring because :P72_CLUBS in the above script is passing 'club_name' rather than 'club_id'. I tired it in 'SQL commands' and when I hard code the id of the club it runs fine. When I replace the id with the names like:

```
l_ids := apex_string.split('club 1:club 2', ':');
```

I get the same error.

So how can I specifically pass the club_id to :P72_CLUB?

Comment: are you sure that is the process giving the error ? If you debug your page you should see the details of what is being executed and the values of the individual page items at that time. I suggest you check that out, the answer is probably there.

Comment: Can you reproduce this on a test workspace on apex.oraclecorp.com ? I'm happy to take a look.

Comment: What's the definition of club_event? Are lobs involved? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33708959/ora-01465-invalid-hex-number-in-oracle-while-using-blob

Comment: @KoenLostrie That would be great. I have reproduced  the page I am working on in a new workspace. I will need your email. Thank you.

Comment: pls post the workspace details: workspace/username/pwd. delete the test user once issue is resolved

Comment: @KoenLostrie Actually after creating the workspace and,  was about to post the details, than I ran events page to make sure everything is in the same state as my main workspace, suddenly the error didn't occur. I have no idea why it works now and didn't work back then. I may have made a silly mistake. Even in may main workspace it is now working. But now deleting and updating the event doesn't work. There are no error message, just the data updating and deletion ins't reflected int the tables itself. I may have to post a separate question for this if I am unable to solve it. For now thank you.